# Why does my useSelector hook always return undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been at this for a while and I can't figure it out. When I dispatch my `populateDatasets` action I can see that my store gets updated just fine in dev tools, but when I try to to access that state in a React component with useSelector it always returns undefined.

Here is how I've configured my store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import datasetReducer from './datasets'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    datasets: datasetReducer
  },
  devTools: true
})
```

Here is the slice that I've created for this piece of state

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const datasetSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'datasets',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    populateDataset: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})

export const { populateDataset } = datasetSlice.actions

export default datasetSlice.reducer
```

And here is where I dispatch the action in my React component

```
const App = () => {
  const { datasets } = useSelector((state) => state.datasets)
  console.log('datasets: ' + datasets)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    csv(FantraxHQData).then(data => {
      data.map((player) => {
        player.isDrafted = false
        return player
      })
      dispatch(populateDataset(data))
    })
    
    csv(FantasyProsData).then(data => {
      data.map((player) => {
        player.isDrafted = false
        return player
      })
      dispatch(populateDataset(data))
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={styles.outter}>
      <MyTeam />
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <DataButtons />
        <DraftBoard />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Again, my store updates just fine when I dispatch the action, but `datasets` is always undefined. Any help would be much appreciated.

Update Solution: The solution was to change `{ datasets }` to `datasets`

Comment: datasets' initial state is an array but you are using object destructuring syntax. Try`const datasets = useSelector((state) => state.datasets)`

Answer (score 2):

Your datasets is an array in your redux store, but you're reading it as a object when
you're using useSelector(). Change the useSelector line to `const datasets = useSelector((state) => state.datasets)`. Don't use the flower bracket on datasets.

Comment: This was it. Thanks